# How to turn off creating accounts in woocommerce checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

How to turn off creating accounts in woocommerce checkout? 
After sending the request, a new account is created.
How to disable this and to have access to unauthorized users?

Answer (score 5):

Go to:

WooCommerce -> Settings -> Accounts tab

You can find the Options are located at the bottom of the page.

Untick -> Enable registration on the "Checkout" page

Save Changes.

Comment: Yes, but after that I do not have access to the unauthorized users.

Answer (score 0):

Registration is something linked directly to Wordpress, not to Woocommerce. Woocommerce provides "helpers" to assist the user on creating his account or logging in if he has one already. But that lies on Wordpress user authentication.

If you want to disable Woocommerce "login hooks" then Ahmed Giani's answer is right.

If you want to disable Wordpress registration you only have go to the settings page, you’ll find the Membership option where you can uncheck the Anyone can register box to disable registration.

Greetings.